# CSS - Float Left/Right Issue

Tags: css, html

You can see the problem here:  http://baycity2014.weebly.com/

I'm having the weirdest issue.  I set-up these divs, and everything works fine.  But when I float a div to the left and the other to right, they seem to "come out" of their container div.  The container div collapses, and the div below goes BELOW the parent div and BEHIND the child div.

If I remove the float: right, no problem.  What's the issue?

HTML:

```
<div id="main-wrap2">
        <div class="block2">
            <div id="left_content">
            {content}
            </div>
            <div id="right_content">
            test<br/>
            test<br/>
            test<br/>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end container -->
    </div><!-- end main-wrap -->
```

CSS:

```
#main-wrap2 {
    width: 100%;
    border: 5px solid;
}

.block2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 940px;
}

#left_content {
    background:#ffffff;
    border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
    box-shadow:  0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
    margin-bottom:6px;
    width: 560px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
}

#right_content {
    width: 270px;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: floated elements are removed them from the parent's sizing/positioning calculations.

Comment: oh crap. How can I fix it?  I need to footer to appear BELOW the divs that are floated left and right.

Comment: cheap workaround is to put in a `<div style="clear: both">` in there, which forces the parent to wrap around the floated elements.

Comment: here you go http://jsfiddle.net/nvBYL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set

```
 #main-wrap2 {
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it :
make a css class `.clr:{clear:both}` 
 and modify ur html code to :

```
<div id="main-wrap2">
    <div class="block2">
        <div id="left_content">
        {content}
        </div>
        <div id="right_content">
        test<br/>
        test<br/>
        test<br/>
        </div> <div class="clr"></div>
    </div><!-- end container -->
</div><!-- end main-wrap -->
```

Hope it will help u :)

Answer (score 0):

Make their parent have:

```
 .block2 {
   overflow:auto;
 }
```

This will allow it to resize with the children.

Answer (score 0):

It's a classic clearfix issue. Explanation: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Basically it uses pseudo-elements to add a div with "clear: both;" on it so it clears.

Answer (score 0):

just like Simon says,put some background to see the difference

```
display:inline-block;
background:aqua;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="main-wrap2">
            <div class="block2">
                <div id="left_content">
                {content}
                </div>
                <div id="right_content">
                test<br/>
                test<br/>
                test<br/>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end container -->
        </div><!-- end main-wrap -->

    #main-wrap2 {
        width: 940px;
border: 5px solid;
margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .block2 {
        display: inline-table !important;
    }

    #left_content {
        background:#ffffff;
        border-radius:5px;
        -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
        box-shadow:  0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
        margin-bottom:6px;
        width: 560px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        float: left;
    }

    #right_content {
        width: 270px;
        border: 1px solid;
        margin-top: 10px;
        float:right;
    }
```

I hope this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

```
#main-wrap2 {
            width: 100%;
            border: 5px solid;
            overflow:auto;
            }
.block2 {
         margin: 0 auto;
         width: 940px;
         overflow:auto;
        }
```

/*use overflow:hidden; or   overflow:auto; in parent div tags.. */

Answer (score -1):

If you float an element, you need to make sure its parent is also floated.